# Format column depend on date cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

How can I create a formula to color the font from the column if line 1 is today?

```
                   A            |       B         |       C
        1  |   21/11/2014       |   22/11/2014    |   23/11/2014
        2  |       xx           |      xxx        |       xx 
        3  |       xx           |      xxx        |       xx
        4  |       xx           |      xxx        |       xx
```

Can I create something automatic? Because I have many columns.

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Format menu, Conditional formatting...

Select "Custom formula is", and enter:

`=A$1=TODAY()`

Check and select the desired text colour, and apply to all columns in your sheet (eg if your columns go to Z, then in Range type `A:Z`).